# Putting 3 different on click functions into one reusable function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have image slider with thumbnails, simple one where I account for left and right arrow clicks that show respective images and thumbnail clicks that load related image. Functions have a lot in common and I'm trying to figure out how to put them into one and use it for all 3 different events, but am having trouble as thumbnail one is slightly different.

```
//Handle next-image click on product single page
    $('.images').on('click', '#next-image', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var current = $('.thumbnail-link.first');

        //Check if thumbnail is last, if it is make first thumbnail next
        if(current.next().hasClass('thumbnail-link')) {
            next = current.next('.thumbnail-link');
        } else {
            next = $('.thumbnail-link').first();
        }

        //Grab image src from data-image attribute
        var image = next.data('image');

        $('.woocommerce-main-image')
        .find('img')
        .animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 300, function() {
            $(this).attr('src', image);
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 300);

        })
        current.removeClass('first');
        next.addClass('first');
    });

    //Handle prev-image click on product single page
    $('.images').on('click', '#prev-image', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var current = $('.thumbnails .first');

        //Check if thumbnail is last, if it is make first thumbnail next
        if(current.prev().hasClass('thumbnail-link')) {
            prev = current.prev('.thumbnail-link');
        } else {
            prev = $('.thumbnail-link').last();
        }

        //Grab image src from data-image attribute
        var image = prev.data('image');

        $('.woocommerce-main-image')
        .find('img')
        .animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 300, function() {
            $(this).attr('src', image);
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
        })
        current.removeClass('first');
        prev.addClass('first');
    });

    //Handle click on thumbnail
    $('.thumbnails').on('click', '.thumbnail-link', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var current = $('.thumbnail-link.first'),
            image = $(this).data('image');

        $('.woocommerce-main-image')
        .find('img')
        .animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 300, function() {
            $(this).attr('src', image);
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
        })

        current.removeClass('first');
        $(this).addClass('first');
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of present code can be made reusable.

I have made the necessary changes and created a single reusable function **handleEvent**

```
// Handle next-image click on product single page
var handleEvent = function(e, currentClass, linkClass, method) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var current = $('.' + currentClass + '.first');
    var next;

    // handles click on thumbnail
    if (typeof method == "undefined") {
        next = $(this);
    } else {
        // Handles next-image and prev-image click on product single page
        // Check if thumbnail is last, if it is make first thumbnail next
        if (current.next().hasClass(linkClass)) {
            next = current.next('.' + linkClass);
        } else {
            next = $('.' + linkClass)[method]();
        }
    }

    // Grab image src from data-image attribute
    var image = next.data('image');

    $('.woocommerce-main-image')
        .find('img')
        .animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 300, function() {
            $(this).attr('src', image);
            $(this).animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 300);
        });

    current.removeClass('first');
    next.addClass('first');
};
```

Example of calling this reusable function from three different events is as follows

```
// Handle next-image click on product single page
$('.images').on('click', '#next-image', function(e) {
    handleEvent(e, 'thumbnail-link', 'thumbnail-link', 'first');
});

// Handle prev-image click on product single page
$('.images').on('click', '#prev-image', function(e) {
    handleEvent(e, 'thumbnails', 'thumbnail-link', 'last');
});

// Handle click on thumbnail
$('.thumbnails').on('click', '.thumbnail-link', function(e) {
    handleEvent(e, 'thumbnail-link');
});
```